# Object can't be converted to a string in MySQLi PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\dash.php on line 20

I am quite fairly new, and being a old-school coder, simply using mysql_result to grab such data, I am unaware of how to go about this. I have a class->function setup.

Line 20 of dash.php contains:

```
echo $user->GetVar('rank', 'Liam', $mysqli);
```

While, the function is:

```
function GetVar($var, $username, $mysqli)
    {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT " . $var . " FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' LIMIT 1");
        return $result;
        $result->close();
    }
```

Now, to my understanding, I am meant to convert $result into a string, but I am not fully aware of how to do so. I've tried using a few methods, but to no avail. So I've come to the community to hopefully get a answer, I've also looked around but noticed that all other threads are asking for num_rows, while I just want to grab the string from the query select.

Comment: you have to fetch it first, gather the results first then return the way you want, an array, etc. actually its in the php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Comment: Exactly. What you are actually trying to return is a (raw?) MySQLi object, which of course cannot be converted as string.

Also. $result->close will never be executed; Since you close the connection after the return statement, just mentionning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fetch it first before echoing the results. Rough Example:

```
function GetVar($var, $username, $mysqli) {
    // make the query
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT ".$var." FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' LIMIT 1");
    $result = $query->fetch_assoc(); // fetch it first
    return $result[$var];
}
```

Then use your function:

```
echo $user->GetVar('rank', 'Liam', $mysqli);
```

Important Note: Since you're starting out, kindly check about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php). Don't directly append user input on your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            echo row['column_name'];
        }
}
$result->close();
```

where you see 'column_name put the name of the column you want to get the string from.

Comment: My upright most apologies, I mustn't have made the thread clear. I'm using a function to retrieve the data. I've updated what the function is.

Comment: $result can not be converted to a string because it is an array